# Does Ember provide a hook to know when there are no outstanding async operations running?

Tags: ember.js

[Protractor](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/) provides a great API wrapper around selenium-webdriver tests, but one of the ways it does that is by using a hook that Angular provides to denote the completion of all outstanding async/polling operations. This includes http calls, intervals, etc.

I'm fairly new to Ember, but I suspect the equivalent would need to be aware of route changes, http calls, and one or more aspects of the run loop. I've [confirmed](https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/1507#issuecomment-62180135) that such a hook would likely open the door to using Protractor with Ember apps, which is ultimately my goal.

So, is there a way to detect when Ember has entered this "quiet" state?

Comment: In test mode all promises are wrapped in a modified promise that is kept track of globally.  I'd have to rummage through the code to find it(and I'm on a phone)

Comment: have you by any chance managed to make protractor work with ember? if yes can you provide some insight/examples? (conf.js - other stuff you might have changed)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how Ember does it (only in test mode, and Test is available on the Ember namespace)

```
function wait(app, value) {
  return Test.promise(function(resolve) {
    // If this is the first async promise, kick off the async test
    if (++countAsync === 1) {
      Test.adapter.asyncStart();
    }

    // Every 10ms, poll for the async thing to have finished
    var watcher = setInterval(function() {
      // 1. If the router is loading, keep polling
      var routerIsLoading = !!app.__container__.lookup('router:main').router.activeTransition;
      if (routerIsLoading) { return; }

      // 2. If there are pending Ajax requests, keep polling
      if (Test.pendingAjaxRequests) { return; }

      // 3. If there are scheduled timers or we are inside of a run loop, keep polling
      if (run.hasScheduledTimers() || run.currentRunLoop) { return; }
      if (Test.waiters && Test.waiters.any(function(waiter) {
        var context = waiter[0];
        var callback = waiter[1];
        return !callback.call(context);
      })) { return; }
      // Stop polling
      clearInterval(watcher);

      // If this is the last async promise, end the async test
      if (--countAsync === 0) {
        Test.adapter.asyncEnd();
      }

      // Synchronously resolve the promise
      run(null, resolve, value);
    }, 10);
  });

}
```